# Проблема при подключении db_connect к postgresql15

Tags: php, postgresql

PHP 8.0.28

Из консоли подключение к БД происходит и выполняется без ошибок:

```
$ php .php
42
```

когда файл подкладываю webserver http выдает 500 ошибку:

> GET /php.php HTTP/1.0" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0"

`php.php`:

```php
<?php
    $dbconn = pg_connect("
          host=host
          dbname=DBname
          user=user
          password=paswd
          port=5432
    ");
    
    $query = 'SELECT 40 + 2';
    $result = pg_query($query);
    $row = pg_fetch_row($result);
    
    echo $row[0];
    
    pg_close($dbconn);
?>
```

Comment: ошибка 500 на apache   из консоли ошибок нет и код выполняется.

Comment: Ошибок нет, потому что ты не включил их...включи..........и как минимум отдебажь код и посмотри на какой строке код перестаёт работать. В дубликате написано и как влюкчить ошибки и как отлаживать код